# Getter behaving differently than method

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-5

I am re-writing a library in TypeScript, and I have changed a function `calcPosition` to a getter `position`. They both have almost the exact same code:

```
public calcPosition (x : number, y : number, w : number, h : number) : Position {
    const colWidth = this.columnWidthInPX;
    if (this.rightToLeft) {
        return {
            right: Math.round(colWidth * x + (x + 1) * this.margin[0]),
            top: Math.round(this.rowHeight * y + (y + 1) * this.margin[1]),
            width: w === Infinity ? w : Math.round(colWidth * w + Math.max(0, w - 1) * this.margin[0]),
            height: h === Infinity ? h : Math.round(this.rowHeight * h + Math.max(0, h - 1) * this.margin[1])
        };
    } else {
        return {
            left: Math.round(colWidth * x + (x + 1) * this.margin[0]),
            top: Math.round(this.rowHeight * y + (y + 1) * this.margin[1]),
            width: w === Infinity ? w : Math.round(colWidth * w + Math.max(0, w - 1) * this.margin[0]),
            height: h === Infinity ? h : Math.round(this.rowHeight * h + Math.max(0, h - 1) * this.margin[1])
        };
    }
}

get position () : Position {
    const colWidth = this.columnWidthInPX;
    if (this.rightToLeft) {
        return {
            right: Math.round(colWidth * this.innerX + (this.innerX + 1) * this.margin[0]),
            top: Math.round(this.rowHeight * this.innerY + (this.innerY + 1) * this.margin[1]),
            width: this.innerW === Infinity ? this.innerW : Math.round(colWidth * this.innerW + Math.max(0, this.innerW - 1) * this.margin[0]),
            height: this.innerH === Infinity ? this.innerH : Math.round(this.rowHeight * this.innerH + Math.max(0, this.innerH - 1) * this.margin[1])
        };
    } else {
        return {
            left: Math.round(colWidth * this.innerX + (this.innerX + 1) * this.margin[0]),
            top: Math.round(this.rowHeight * this.innerY + (this.innerY + 1) * this.margin[1]),
            width: this.innerW === Infinity ? this.innerW : Math.round(colWidth * this.innerW + Math.max(0, this.innerW - 1) * this.margin[0]),
            height: this.innerH === Infinity ? this.innerH : Math.round(this.rowHeight * this.innerH + Math.max(0, this.innerH - 1) * this.margin[1])
        };
    }
}
```

Every time the `calcPosition` method is called from within the library, it calls it with the same arguments:

```
pos = this.calcPosition(this.innerX, this.innerY, this.innerW, this.innerH);
```

As you can see above, I did the quite sensible thing of converting it to a getter that uses those properties directly rather than passing them in as arguments. Note that those properties are simple types--numbers, not objects--so I doubt this has to do with reference issues. Yet, by changing a single line--the line above--to using `this.position` instead of `this.calcPosition()`, my application behaves differently. **What causes my getter to behave differently than my method?**

Comment: And what is the difference?